# How to disable Google Assistant button programmatically Android TV

Tags: java, android, google-assist-api

I'm creating an Android TV app and I want to do a custom method to work the the Google Assistant button in the remote, the method works fine but every time I press the Google Assistant button the google assistant shows up along with my method (for obvious reason...).
I was wondering can I disable Google Assistant in my app?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, you will need to show us your code and configuration if anyone is going to be able to help you.

Comment: What do u need exactly

Comment: We need enough information to know what is actually happening, based on what you have tried so far.

Comment: Can't disable the button, but in such cases there generally is an API you can use that accesses the same thing as the button. Logcat will tell you something about what the button does; the android source code will contain the code. GL;HF.